# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base D:\Program Files\Tomcat\tomcat-7.0\webapps\ROOT does not exist or is not a readable directory

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea, war

I noticed there are already several posts about this error here,
somebody said it's a problem cause by the permission
somebody else said it's caused by a xxx.xml file

But I encountered another problem:

I deployed my webapp by intellij, and used maven to do the build and package job inside intellij, and the tomcat is configured inside it as well.
Every time I make a new artifact into the directory tomcat/webapps/ROOT/ , I can see the xxx.war file outside the directory, and when I put it into the ROOT/ and then try browsering, it gives me this Exception

```
 Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\user\.IntelliJIdea2016.1\system\tomcat\Unnamed_arius\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml
 12, 2016 4:07:27  org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
warining: A docBase D:\Program Files\Tomcat\tomcat-7.0\webapps\admin.war inside the host appBase has been specified, and will be ignored
12, 2016 4:07:27  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base D:\Program Files\Tomcat\tomcat-7.0\webapps\ROOT does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:5197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5386)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:679)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1966)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I also noticed that all the elements under webapps have gone.
How do I make this .war deployed correctly and stay stable? I don't know whether its related to the error occurred, but it's a problem itself.

Comment: Document base D:\Program Files\Tomcat\tomcat-7.0\webapps\ROOT does not exist or is not a readable directory 

Message clearly states that either the webapp is not preset or if present, it is not readable. So, it can be permission issue as well deployment configuration issue.

Comment: The build seems fine and you should not put your war inside the `ROOT` directory. IJ is publishing your artifact correclty, and `ROOT` is a separate [default web application](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/security-howto.html#ROOT) deployed under Tomcat which is complaining it can not read its content for some reason. Try to figure out why it's happening or just remove it.